# How can I specialize a template using is_base_of without being ambiguous with the primary template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, sfinae

Using the code below, I get a compiler complaint about the call to get_code being ambiguous between the first two templates.  How can I craft the code to detect a base class while also providing specialized forms?  For example, if later I had `class C : A {}` which should also return `ACLASS`.

```
class A {};
class B : A {};
class D {};

enum Code { UNKNOWN, ACLASS, DCLASS };

template <typename T>
Code get_code() { return Code::UNKNOWN; }

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, Code>::type
get_code() { return Code::ACLASS; }

template <>
inline Code get_code<D>() { return Code::DCLASS; }

Code test1 = get_code<D>();  // OK, chooses DCLASS
Code test2 = get_code<B>();  // ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

Comment: Is [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/N3MCPAclgAfI63J4) what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, this looks like a good solution too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to deactivate the unknown case when `T` is base of `A`

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if< ! std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, Code>::type
get_code() // -----------^ 
 { return Code::UNKNOWN; }
```

otherwise, when `T` is base of `A`, the compiler can use two version of `get_code()` and can't choose the right one (ambigous call)

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B : A {};
class C {};
class D {};

enum Code { UNKNOWN, ACLASS, DCLASS };

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, Code>::type
get_code()
 { std::cout << "code U" << std::endl; return Code::UNKNOWN; }

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, Code>::type
get_code()
 { std::cout << "code A" << std::endl; return Code::ACLASS; }

template <>
Code get_code<D>()
 { std::cout << "code D" << std::endl; return Code::DCLASS; }

int main()
 {
   get_code<A>(); // print A
   get_code<B>(); // print A
   get_code<C>(); // print U
   get_code<D>(); // print D
 }
```

But I propose you another way, based on tag dispatching, to obtain the same result without using SFINAE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B : A {};
class C {};
class D {};

enum Code { UNKNOWN, ACLASS, DCLASS };

Code gc2h (std::true_type const &)
 { std::cout << "code A" << std::endl; return Code::ACLASS; }

Code gc2h (std::false_type const &)
 { std::cout << "code U" << std::endl; return Code::UNKNOWN; }

template <typename T>
Code gc2 ()
 { return gc2h(typename std::is_base_of<A, T>::type {}); }

template <>
Code gc2<D>()
 { std::cout << "code D" << std::endl; return Code::DCLASS; }

int main()
 {
   gc2<A>(); // print A
   gc2<B>(); // print A
   gc2<C>(); // print U
   gc2<D>(); // print D
 }
```

Another way can be pass the value of `std::is_base_of` as template parameter for the helper function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B : A {};
class C {};
class D {};

enum Code { UNKNOWN, ACLASS, DCLASS };

template <bool>
Code gc3h ();

template <>
Code gc3h<true> ()
 { std::cout << "code A" << std::endl; return Code::ACLASS; }

template <>
Code gc3h<false> ()
 { std::cout << "code U" << std::endl; return Code::UNKNOWN; }

template <typename T>
Code gc3 ()
 { return gc3h<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value>(); }

template <>
Code gc3<D>()
 { std::cout << "code D" << std::endl; return Code::DCLASS; }

int main()
 {
   gc3<A>(); // print A
   gc3<B>(); // print A
   gc3<C>(); // print U
   gc3<D>(); // print D
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

Another possible solution.

If you can accept that your function is a `static` method of a template `class` (or `struct`), and if you can accept that is called as `gc4<T>::func()` instead of `gc4<T>()`, another way, based on partial specialization, follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B : A {};
class C {};
class D {};

enum Code { UNKNOWN, ACLASS, DCLASS };

template <typename T, bool = std::is_base_of<A, T>::value>
struct gc4;

template <typename T>
struct gc4<T, true>
 {
   static_assert(true == std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "!");

   static Code func ()
    { std::cout << "code A" << std::endl; return Code::ACLASS; }
 };

template <typename T>
struct gc4<T, false>
 {
   static_assert(false == std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "!!");

   static Code func ()
    { std::cout << "code U" << std::endl; return Code::UNKNOWN; }
 };

template <>
struct gc4<D>
 {
   static Code func ()
    { std::cout << "code D" << std::endl; return Code::DCLASS; }
 };

int main()
 {
   gc4<A>::func(); // print A
   gc4<B>::func(); // print A
   gc4<C>::func(); // print U
   gc4<D>::func(); // print D
 }
```

The `static_assert()`s are added to avoid that someone can circumvent the solution calling something like

```
gc4<A, false>::func();
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  I appreciate having detailed code samples as well as multiple working options.

Comment: @Glenn - look also at the link proposed by Skypjack: show another type of solution based on two function where the enabled, via `std::enable_if`, is favourite (when available) over the other; so there is no need to delete the second function when the first is enabled.

Comment: @Glenn - Because you appreciate multiple working options, I've added another one.

Comment: Having all these options certainly expands my understand of templating.  Thanks.